# I need some advice with creating custom component QML libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qml

I have written some QML components which I would like to reuse in many projects.

Currently, what I do, is create the components using QtCreator (test it, etc).

If I want to use these component from several applications (using VS2010) what I do is to embed them in a QRC file. But I need to copy every QML needed file for each new VS2010 solution/project ... I would like to distribute them as plugins or libraries and not having to create new QRCs, etc.

What should I do?

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

One options is to create a QML Extension plugin: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlextensionplugin.html